# Get CruiseControl descriptive errors

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, msbuild-buildengine

My cruisecontrol runs two nant scripts and it builds by using msbuild. Msbuild is failing without giving any errors. Is there any way to get more error details? Below is how I have configured publishers.

```
<publishers>
            <email from="cruise@xx..com.au" mailhost="stat-server" includeDetails="TRUE">
                <users>
....
</users>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can view the CruiseControl.net Build log through the web application "View Build Log" link. It gives all the details of the build process.

Answer (score 1):

I normally start of running the build scripts from the command line on your build server.

You can also run MSBuild with a verbosity switch, that increase the amount of debug information.  That will at least give you a idea of where the problem lies, perhaps your cruise control server is fine.

```
msbuild.exe <buildFile.msbuild> /v:d
```

Comment: I managed to run the msbuild. Ignore my previous message. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note - if you running the noconsolelogger switch you are not going to see any build errors in your cruise control dash board